# Print selected lines by number in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I can print range of lines (118 to 122) as:

`sed -n '118,122p;16483q' large_text_file`

But how do I print lines 188, 144 and 154 (in the same order) in unix?

Comment: How should a line number that's not present in the input file be handled? How should the same line number specified multiple times be handled? e.g. given a 5 line input file generated by `seq 5` what should the output of `cmd 4 2 17 2` be for the `cmd` you want to create?

Answer (score 4):

For printing lines of a big file in a specified order `awk` will be more suitable:

```
# prepare sample input data
printf 'line # %s\n' {1..500} > file

# run awk
awk -v nums='188 144 154' '
BEGIN {
   tot = n = split(nums, arr)       # split and store numbers in an array
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++)             # convert to lines array with key as numbers
      lines[arr[i]]
}
NR in lines {                       # if current line no is in lines array
   lines[NR] = $0                   # store current line as value
   if (!--tot)                      # decrement total count
      exit                          # exit when we have processed all 
}
END {                               # print all stored lines
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      print lines[arr[i]]
}' file
```

**Output:**

```
line # 188
line # 144
line # 154
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, in my testing on a 7 MB file this `awk` solution is running 4x faster than `ed` solution.

Comment: You could make it a bit more efficient still by moving the `tot` comparison inside the `NR in lines` block since that's the only place where `tot` changes: `if (!--tot) exit`. The comment should say decrement, btw, not increment. I wonder if it's necessary to test for `arr[i] in lines` before printing in the END to handle cases where a `nums` number is larger than the number of lines in the input? The OP didn't say how to handle that, nor how to handle duplicate line numbers in `nums`.

Comment: Thanks so much Ed. Actually moving `if (!--tot) exit` inside the `NR in lines` block is making it more slow in my 7MB file testing. Other suggestions are quite good but I will wait for OP to respond  before making changes.

Comment: You're welcome. I can't imagine how that's possible though given where it is right now if you have a 1,000 line input file and want to print 3 lines then the condition will be tested 1,000 times whereas if you move it inside the block it'll only be tested 3 times. Oh well...

Comment: I can see how `if (!tot--) exit` would take longer since `tot` would never get to zero and so it'd never `exit`, it'd always read the whole file.

Comment: When I say "never get to zero" I of course mean when the condition is tested - it'll become zero **after** being tested but that;s too late. FWIW I just tested the 2 approaches on MacOS using GNU awk and BSD awk and on third-run timing saw a slight speed up from both awks with `if (!--tot) exit` and using `nums='188 144 154000'` and a 500,000 line input file.

Comment: Ah that's a good point. `NR in lines{lines[NR] = $0; if (!--tot) exit}` does the job and exits correctly. However there is hardly any appreciable time gain w.r.t having `!tot{exit}` separately.

Comment: Right, there'll be a bigger time difference depending on how many line numbers you want to match and how far down the input file they are but at the end of the day it's just one comparison so it's not going to make a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `ed`:

```
printf "%s\n" 188p 144p 154p | ed -s large_text_file
```

though its suitability does depend on *how* large the file is.

---

As mentioned in comments, if you just have an address, `ed` assumes the **p**rint command. So if the line numbers you want to print are in a bash array, using that instead of hardcoding the numbers directly in the command becomes trivial:

```
declare -a lines=(188 144 154)
printf "%s\n" "${lines[@]}" | ed -s large_text_file
```

Comment: Works without the `p`, at least on this side.

Comment: @Jetchisel Yeah, just an address has an implicit `p`. I like to be explicit though... but come to think of it, if the line numbers are in a bash array, then using `printf "%s\n" "${foo[@]}"` would work well.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed, printf, sort):

```
printf "%s\n" 90p 90q 1,5p |
cat -n |
sed -E 's/(.*\t)(.*)p/\2{h;s#^#\1#p;g}/;s/(.*\t)(.*)q/\2q/' |
sed -nf - file |
sort -ns |
sed 's/[^\t]*\t//'
```

Print each line number on a separate line. The command set is either `p` or `q`.

Add ranking index to commands.

Create a sed script and insert ranking index in front of each line to be printed.

Read `file` and print lines or quit regardless of ranking index.

Sort by ranking index and keep original order.

Print results with ranking index removed.

N.B. Once the quit `q` line number is reached in `file`, no further processing of `file` is executed. Only one `q` command allowed.